# trigger mouseMoveEvent of several QGraphicsItem at the same time

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem

When I select several QGraphicsItem (with Ctrl key) I can move them together, but the mouseMoveEvent is triggered only for the item that actually receives the event. Is there a way to make every selected items receive the event ? I can't find it in Qt's doc.

Could I group selected items together and handle it within QGraphicsView's mouseMoveEvent ?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no default way to do what you want as far as I know. Something you could do is the following:

- Subclass `QGraphicsScene` and implement the `mouseMoveEvent`
- In the mouse move event check if there is an item at the event position using the `itemAt` function
- If there is an item and it is selected (`isSelected`), get all selected items of the scene.
- For all selected items call the same function you would call.

Sample code follows:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent) 
{
    QPointF mousePosition = mouseEvent->scenePos();
    QGraphicsItem* pItem = itemAt(mousePosition.x(), mousePosition.y());
    if (pItem == NULL)
    {
        QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
        return;
    }

    if (pItem->isSelected() == false)  
    {
        QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
        return;
    }

    // Get all selected items
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> items = selectedItems();

    for (unsinged i=0; i<items.count(); i++)
        // Do what you want to do when a mouse move over a selected item.
        items[i]->doSomething(); 

    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading between the lines of your question a little, but it sounds like you might be better served by implementing `QGraphicsItem::itemChange` on your `QGraphicsItem` class(es). This will get called whenever the position changes--whether by mouse, keyboard, programmatic, etc. You can even cancel the change if you want to.

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange